# Getting error after adding onclick event

Tags: php

Following is my php code which i am using to return image, but i am getting errors. Kindly let me know what i did wrong.
The error does not happen if I remove onclick event from the following code.

```
return ('<img onclick="window.open('http://google.com','_blank')" src="'.$content.'" alt=""/>');
```

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't escape single quotes:

```
return ('<img onclick="window.open(\'http://google.com\', \'_blank\')" src="'.$content.'" alt=""/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape characters:

```
return ('<img onclick="window.open(\'http://google.com\',\'_blank\')" src="'.$content.'" alt=""/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use back slash like it

```
return ('<img onclick="window.open(\'http://google.com\',\'_blank\')" src="'.$content.'" alt=""/>');
```